# How to create a customized android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to figure out how to make a customized android keyboard. I want additional keys in the keyboard like page up, page down, etc. I want these keys to perform the actions that I want them to do. For example,
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/hackers-keyboard-is-a-full-5-row-on-screen-keyboard-for-android/

Have a look at the above provided keyboard layouts. How can i do this? Any useful pointers??

Thank you in advance,
Mohsin

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an input method.

Read more about it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html), [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html).